# Подсчет вхождений слова на листе

Tags: excel

Суть - есть текстовый файл и большой список слов, которые нужно проверить на наличие в этом файле. Принято решение использовать Excel. Текст целиком вставлен в лист. Соответственно, перевод строки в тексте превращается в перевод строки в таблице, каждая строка попадает в первую ячейку столбца (текст слишком большой чтобы целиком вставить в одну ячейку). На соседнем листе столбец с искомыми словами. Нужно во втором столбце этого листа вывести счетсчик вхождений этого слова в первый лист. Пример:

Лист 1

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
-------------------------
| В лесу родилась елочка,
| В лесу она росла.     |
| Зимой и летом стройная,
| Зеленая была  |       |
```

Лист 2 (должен стать)

```
|   A   |   B   |   C   |
-------------------------
|  Лесу |   2   |       |
|   В   |   2   |       |
| летом |   1   |       |
| Ктулху|   0   |       |
```

Вижу функцию счетесли, но в примерах она ищет полное совпадение ячеек. Какую формулу следует использвоать в столбце B листа 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество ячеек, в которых встречается искомое слово (одно или с повторами):

```
=СЧЁТ(1/(ДЛСТР(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4)<>ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4;A1;))))
```

Считаем все вхождения искомого слова:

```
=СУММ(ДЛСТР(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4;A1;)))/ДЛСТР(A1)
```

Формулы массива, вводятся тремя клавишами *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*

Если функцию *СУММ* заменить на *СУММПРОИЗВ*, формулу можно вводить как обычную.

Для счета ячеек меняем *СЧЕТ* и изменяем отображение условия:

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(--(ДЛСТР(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4)<>ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4;A1;))))
```

Считаем все вхождения искомого слова без учета регистра (*"Лес" = "лес"*):

```
=СУММПРОИЗВ(ДЛСТР(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(ПРОПИСН(Лист1!$A$1:$A$4);ПРОПИСН(A1);)))/ДЛСТР(A1)
```

Comment: Не понимаю как вводить. Копирую вторую команду в ячейку B1, нажимаю Ctrl+Shift+Enter. В ячейке остается ошибка #ИМЯ? ._.

Comment: Курсор должен находиться в строке формул. Если локаль не русская, нужно перевести функции на английский вариант

Comment: Русская -.- Если быть точным, ввожу в C4 
`{=СУММ(ДЛСТР(Лист7!$A$1:$A$2721)-ДЛСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(Лист7!A1:A2721;A4;"")))/ДЛСТР(A4)}` Никогда не понимал механизма формул массивов ._.

Comment: Второй раз диапазон не закреплен. Excel или Google?

Comment: MS Excel 2016 :3 Да, я заметил, когда вставил коммент, уже поправил, но изменений не последовало.

Comment: Фигурные скобки не писать, они  дожны появиться после нажатия трех клавиш. Ошибка  *#ИМЯ?* говорит о том, что или функция написана неправильно, или диапазон... Возможно, в названия попала латиница или в диапазоны - кириллица.. Вставил формулу из Вашего сообщения - работает.